# How to employ Excel data validation such that exactly two decimal places can be entered?

Tags: excel

Problem Statement:

1. Data Validation in an Excel cell.
2. User should only be able to enter exactly 2 decimal digits. So, 11.00, but not 11 or 11.0.

What I've tried:

```
INT(A1*100) = A1*100
```

as the data validation formula. Sadly, it allows for no or single decimals as well.

Comment: to excel `11=11.0=11.00`, unless the cell is formatted as text.  The display can be changed to display the two decimals.  But when entering `11.00` Excel will convert it to `11` before any thing can be done to check.

Comment: ^^^ which is why something like `=AND(ISNUMBER(A1),MID(A1,LEN(A1)-2,1)=".")` doesn't work when you try to enter `11.00`. Also note that calling `LEN` on a cell that has `11.00` entered returns `2`, not `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code I wrote back in 2011 to control TextBox input for numbers. I updated it to control the currency datatype's decimal places. It's a bit long as it covers all numeric datatypes but you can zero in on the Currency type. Please read the comments as they explain the operation of the code. Of course, you could just use the short version:

```
Public Function bForceDecimals(zStrValue As Variant, iDecimals As Variant) As Boolean

   Dim iDecLoc As Integer
   
   '*** Check for no Decimal ***
   iDecLoc = InStr(zStrValue, ".")
   If iDecLoc = 0 Then
     bForceDecimals = False
   Else
     If Len(zStrValue) - iDecLoc = iDecimals Then
       bForceDecimals = True
     Else
       bForceDecimals = False
     End If
   End If
   
End Function 'bForceDecimals
```

You'd call this from a Before_Update event.

Here's the long version for anyone who is interested. Note, it is NOT set to check for EXACT number of currency decimal places like the above code!

```
Option Explicit

#Const cModeDebug = False  '*** Set to True when debugging & False for Production

'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+
'-------------------------|  bVerifyTextBoxNumber() |-------------| 07/22/20 |
'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+
'Called by: Any procedure needing to verify numeric input!
'Notes: This routine only verifies numbers NOT DATES!
'       If the optional arguments are used for Lower & Upper Limits
'       the values passed are considered INVALID entries, i.e. a lower limit of
'       Zero will NOT allow a Zero value entry! and an upper limit of 1,000 will
'       NOT allow a value greater than 999 for whole numbers and 999.999... for
'       Single, Double, and Currency types. If passing only an upper limit you
'       must include the commas, i.e.
'         -->    bVerifyTextBoxNumber(iDatatype,zStrValue,,vUpperLimit)
'       Conversion functions, e.g. CInt & CLng round funny...
'       If the fractional part is EXACTLY .5 they round to the nearest
'       EVEN number, thus; 2.5 rounds to 2 while 3.5 rounds to 4!
'       This function, despite it's name can also be used to verify input
'       from the INPUTBOX function.
'  Decimal placess (vDecimals) are currently only controled on the Currency
'  type. If not specified will default to 2 (U.S. standard).
'  You can extend the code to other type if desired.

Public Function bVerifyTextBoxNumber(iDataType As Integer, zStrValue As Variant, _
                                     Optional vLowerLimit As Variant, _
                                     Optional vUpperLimit As Variant, _
                                     Optional vDecimals As Variant) As Boolean

  Dim bErrNumeric    As Boolean
  Dim bErrCommas     As Boolean
  Dim zDatatypes(18) As String
  Dim zErrorData     As String
  
  zDatatypes(0) = "vbEmpty"
  zDatatypes(1) = "vbNull"
  zDatatypes(2) = "vbInteger"
  zDatatypes(3) = "vbLong"
  zDatatypes(4) = "vbSingle"
  zDatatypes(5) = "vbDouble"
  zDatatypes(6) = "vbCurrency"
  zDatatypes(7) = "vbDate"
  zDatatypes(8) = "vbString"
  zDatatypes(9) = "vbObject"
  zDatatypes(10) = "vbError"
  zDatatypes(11) = "vbBoolean"
  zDatatypes(12) = "Unknown"
  zDatatypes(13) = "vbDataObject"
  zDatatypes(14) = "vbDecimal"
  zDatatypes(15) = "Unknown"
  zDatatypes(16) = "Unknown"
  zDatatypes(17) = "vbByte"

  On Error GoTo ErrorTrap:
  
  bVerifyTextBoxNumber = True
  bErrNumeric = False
  bErrNumeric = Not IsNumeric(zStrValue)
  bErrCommas = InStr(zStrValue, ",") > 0
  
  If bErrNumeric Or bErrCommas Then
    bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
    Exit Function
  End If
  
  #If cModeDebug Then   '*** Construct Debug message ***
    zErrorData = "Lower Limit is GREATER than or Equal to Upper Limit!" & _
               vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Data Type Requested: " & vbTab & zDatatypes(iDataType) & _
               vbCrLf & "Data Value Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & zStrValue & vbCrLf & _
               "Lower Limit Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & _
               IIf(Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit), vLowerLimit, "None") & vbCrLf & _
               "Upper Limit Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & _
               IIf(Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit), vUpperLimit, "None") & vbCrLf & _
               "Decimal Places Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & _
               IIf(Not IsMissing(vDecimals), vDecimals, "None")
  #End If
  
  Select Case iDataType
  
  Case vbCurrency
  
     '*** Check for no Decimal ***
     iDecLoc = InStr(zStrValue, ".")
     If iDecLoc = 0 Then
       bForceDecimals = True
       Return
     End If
  
      If IsMissing(vDecimals) Then vDecimals = 2
      If Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit) Then
        If CCur(zStrValue) <= CCur(vLowerLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      If Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit) Then
        If CCur(zStrValue) >= CCur(vUpperLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      If Len(zStrValue) - InStr(zStrValue, ".") > vDecimals Then
        bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
      End If
      
#If cModeDebug Then
      If (Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit)) And _
         (Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit)) Then
        If CCur(vLowerLimit) >= CCur(vUpperLimit) Then
          MsgBox zErrorData, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
                 "bVerifyTextBoxNumber()- Error: Invalid Call to Function"
        End If
      End If
#End If
 
  Case vbSingle
      If Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit) Then
        If CSng(zStrValue) <= CSng(vLowerLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      If Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit) Then
        If CSng(zStrValue) >= CSng(vUpperLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      
#If cModeDebug Then
      If (Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit)) And _
         (Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit)) Then
        If CSng(vLowerLimit) >= CSng(vUpperLimit) Then
          MsgBox zErrorData, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
                 "bVerifyTextBoxNumber()- Error: Invalid Call to Function"
        End If
      End If
#End If

  Case vbDouble
      If Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit) Then
        If CDbl(zStrValue) <= CDbl(vLowerLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      If Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit) Then
        If CDbl(zStrValue) >= CDbl(vUpperLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      
#If cModeDebug Then
      If (Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit)) And _
         (Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit)) Then
        If CDbl(vLowerLimit) >= CDbl(vUpperLimit) Then
          MsgBox zErrorData, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
                 "bVerifyTextBoxNumber()- Error: Invalid Call to Function"
        End If
      End If
#End If
  
  Case vbInteger
      If Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit) Then
        If CInt(zStrValue) <= CInt(vLowerLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      If Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit) Then
        If CInt(zStrValue) >= CInt(vUpperLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      If bCheckforDecimal(zStrValue) Then bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
      
#If cModeDebug Then
      If (Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit)) And _
         (Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit)) Then
        If CInt(vLowerLimit) >= CInt(vUpperLimit) Then
          MsgBox zErrorData, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
                 "bVerifyTextBoxNumber()- Error: Invalid Call to Function"
        End If
      End If
#End If
  
  Case vbLong
      If Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit) Then
        If CLng(zStrValue) <= CLng(vLowerLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      If Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit) Then
        If CLng(zStrValue) >= CLng(vUpperLimit) Then
          bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
        End If
      End If
      If bCheckforDecimal(zStrValue) Then bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
       
#If cModeDebug Then
      If (Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit)) And _
         (Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit)) Then
        If CLng(vLowerLimit) >= CLng(vUpperLimit) Then
          MsgBox zErrorData, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
                 "bVerifyTextBoxNumber()- Error: Invalid Call to Function"
        End If
      End If
#End If
 
  Case Else
      MsgBox "The data type { " & zDatatypes(iDataType) & _
             " } is not supported by the bVerifyTextBoxNumber function." & _
             vbCrLf & "Supported datatypes:" & vbCrLf & _
             "vbCurrency; vbDouble; vbInteger;" & vbCrLf & _
             "vbLong; and vbSingle", _
             vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
             "bVerifyTextBoxNumber()- Error: Unsupported Data Type"
      bVerifyTextBoxNumber = False
      
  End Select    '*** Case iDataType ***
  
  Exit Function
  
ErrorTrap:

  zErrorData = "Data Type Requested: " & vbTab & zDatatypes(iDataType) & vbCrLf & _
               "Data Value Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & zStrValue & vbCrLf & _
               "Lower Limit Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & _
               IIf(Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit), vLowerLimit, "None") & vbCrLf & _
               "Upper Limit Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & _
               IIf(Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit), vUpperLimit, "None")
  
  Select Case Err()
        Case 6:      '*** OverFlow Error - Number too large for type ***
           MsgBox "One of the arguments passed caused an Overflow error:" & _
           vbCrLf & zErrorData, _
           vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
           "bVerifyTextBoxNumber()- Error: Argument out of Range"
           Exit Function
        Case 13:    '*** Type Mismatch Error - Can't convert to number ***
            MsgBox "One of the arguments passed caused an Type Mismatch error:" & _
           vbCrLf & zErrorData, _
           vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
           "bVerifyTextBoxNumber()- Error: Argument out of Range"
           Exit Function
        Case Else
           MsgBox "Error Number: " & Format(Err.Number) & vbCrLf & _
                  "Error Description: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                  "Contact your system programmer immediately!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                  zErrorData, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
                  "bVerifyTextBoxNumber()- Error: Unknown Error"

  End Select

End Function    '*** bVerifyTextBoxNumber ***

Function bCheckforDecimal(zStrValue As Variant) As Boolean

'*** Returns True if number contains decimal VALUES!
'*** Returns False even if there is a decimal but no decimal values.

  Dim iDecimalLoc    As Integer

  '*** Check for decimal point. If decimal present and not last character ERROR ***
  iDecimalLoc = InStr(zStrValue, ".")
  If iDecimalLoc <> 0 And iDecimalLoc < Len(zStrValue) Then
    bCheckforDecimal = True
  Else
    bCheckforDecimal = False
  End If
  
End Function

'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+
'-------------------------|   bVerifyTextBoxDate()  |-------------| 08/26/10 |
'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+

Public Function bVerifyTextBoxDate(zDateValue As String, _
                                   Optional vLowerLimit As Variant, _
                                   Optional vUpperLimit As Variant)
                                   
   Dim zErrorData As String

On Error GoTo DateError

    bVerifyTextBoxDate = True

    If Not IsDate(zDateValue) Then
      bVerifyTextBoxDate = False
      Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit) Then
     If CDate(zDateValue) <= CDate(vLowerLimit) Then
       bVerifyTextBoxDate = False
     End If
    End If
    
    If Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit) Then
     If CDate(zDateValue) >= CDate(vUpperLimit) Then
       bVerifyTextBoxDate = False
     End If
    End If
    
#If cModeDebug Then
    zErrorData = "Lower Limit is GREATER than or Equal to Upper Limit!" & _
               vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "Data Value Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & zDateValue & vbCrLf & _
               "Lower Limit Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & _
               IIf(Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit), vLowerLimit, "None") & vbCrLf & _
               "Upper Limit Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & _
               IIf(Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit), vUpperLimit, "None")
    If (Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit)) And _
       (Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit)) Then
      If CDate(vLowerLimit) >= CDate(vUpperLimit) Then
        MsgBox zErrorData, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
               "bVerifyTextBoxDate()- Error: Invalid Call to Function"
      End If
    End If
#End If
    
    Exit Function
    
DateError:

  zErrorData = "One of the data values passed can not be converted " & _
               "into a date!" & vbCrLf & _
               "Data Value Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & zDateValue & vbCrLf & _
               "Lower Limit Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & _
               IIf(Not IsMissing(vLowerLimit), vLowerLimit, "None") & vbCrLf & _
               "Upper Limit Passed: " & vbTab & vbTab & _
               IIf(Not IsMissing(vUpperLimit), vUpperLimit, "None")
               
  Select Case Err()
        Case 13:    '*** Type Mismatch Error - Can't convert to date ***
            MsgBox zErrorData, _
           vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
           "bVerifyTextBoxDate()- Error: Argument Type Mismatch"
           Exit Function
        Case Else
           MsgBox "Error Number: " & Format(Err.Number) & vbCrLf & _
                  "Error Description: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                  "Contact your system programmer immediately!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                  zErrorData, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
                  "bVerifyTextBoxDate()- Error: Unknown Error"

  End Select

    
End Function    '*** bVerifyTextBoxDate() ***
```

Answer (score -1):

An example data validation formula that works well for me is as follows:

```
=H2=ROUND(H2,2)
```